# Acorn fonts F letter does not print as the other letters

Tags: fonts

[image: Acorn alphabet example]

This is a printout of the Acorn.tex file that is included in the TeX distribution, it obvious that there is a problem with the letter F, the acorns and leaves are not shown as in the other letters. In the example shown in the catalogue (https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/acorn/example.html) there is no difference between F and the other letters. I have been looking in the different Acorn files the definition of the letter in order to redefine it but could not find it. I guess if some user has found this problem before and can provide any help.

Comment: If I look at an example at high resolution, I see no difference [picture (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aS6VL.png). It's a question of font hinting, I guess, which shows up at low resolution.

Comment: I do not think that this is due to the resolution, if such was the case the effect would be the same in all letters in this is not the case, leaves and acorns are clearly seen in all lettes but F

Comment: As I said, the problem might reside in font hinting, possibly forgotten for the F.