# Ornate capital letters

Tags: letters, ornamental-fonts

I was reading some Algebra notes and the letters that the author uses to start each chapter caught my attention. Does anyone know what package is needed to use those letters?

[image]

Comment: See `...texlive/2023/texmf-dist/doc/fonts/initials`

Comment: You would find https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/ useful for questions like this.

Comment: The ornate letters used to start chapters are called "drop caps" and one can use the package `lettrine` to produce them (https://ctan.org/pkg/lettrine?lang=en). You will need to choose a font for the drop caps or `lettrine` will just make a larger document-font letter.

Comment: From the other comments: this one seems to be close https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/acorn/

Comment: An [example of use](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74609/11604) of this font as drop capitals, but indeed, you should take a look to the above links.

Comment: It's definitely `acorn`, but look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/590248/4427. The problem hasn't been fixed.